# iperf installation and use

Tags: installation, bandwidth, wide-area-network, iperf

I would like to use iperf to test my WAN bandwidth connection. However, I can't find a good method to install and administer it.  I'm a Windows guy and don't know much about Linux, and googling iperf didn't help much.  Do I need to run the server part on a machine inside my network and have it test the WAN bandwidth and send it to a machine outside the network?  The details are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perform a [search for iperf](http://serverfault.com/search?q=iperf) here on SF and you will find lots of examples and details about usage of iperf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, yes.. you need two hosts running iperf at each end:

- One server with the command: `iperf -s`
- One client with the command: `iperf -c ser.ver.ip.address`

Here's a windows binary you can use: https://nocweboldcst.ucf.edu/files/iperf.exe (run it from the command line in windows)

Here's a tutorial I've used for a while that pretty much has most of whatever information you need to run it successfully: http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php *(you can find out about extra options you can use with it... my favorite for bandwidth throughput would be -u for UDP traffic tests--on both client and server)*